# Get-WindowsOptionalFeature failing from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, iis

I am trying to check if windows server 2012 has IIS installed.

I am using following program in C#. It is working fine in windows 7 / 10 but giving error in windows server 2012.

```
public static String ExecutePoswershellScript(String filepath)
{

    log.Info(filepath);

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = filepath;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    log.Info(output);
    string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    if (err.Length>0)
    {
        log.Error(err);
    }
   
   // log.Info(output + "");
    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
    return output;
}
```

Error is as follows

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
At line:1 char:64
+ ... ocess; Import-Module Dism; Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where ...
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsOptionalFeature], CO
MException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.GetWindowsOptionalFeatureC
ommand
```

when I execute the command from powershell in windows server 2012 it works , only when I execute uing C# it fails

[PowershellCommand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1OzO.png)

PowerShell version

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.117
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Please let me know if needs to be changed

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? It is rather simple to get everything from Windows registry https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components so calling a PowerShell script is not the fastest way.

Comment: @LexLi, discovery is fine but I also want to enable Feature if not installed and then I receive same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Desktops OSs use

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online
```

On Servers OSs use

```
Get-WindowsFeature *IIS*
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the IIS, right click on the applications application pool and go to "advanced settings" and change "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to "TRUE". Restart your website and it should work.

Or In Visual Studio, Right Click your project -> On the left pane click the Build tab, under Platform Target select x86.